# doctrine migrations with postgresql : on delete cascade not anymore in migrations

Tags: postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm

When I add a foreign key with symfony maker, then generate my migration whith `php bin/console d:m:diff` there is no more this instruction :

```
ON DELETE CASCADE
```

For example, I had a ManyToOne

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=User::class)
 */
private User $userCreation;
```

In the past (08/04/2022), my migration was that kind :

```
    public function up(Schema $schema): void
{
    ....
    $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE myTable ADD CONSTRAINT FK_21DFB03EA76ED395 FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES utilisateur (id) ON DELETE CASCADE NOT DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE');
}
```

Now, if I do the same, I have :

```
public function up(Schema $schema): void
{
    ....
    $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE myTable ADD CONSTRAINT FK_D80C797B46501A53 FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES utilisateur (id) NOT DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE');
}
```

Now, I must add this orm description to find again the `ON DELETE CASCADE` instruction :

```
@ORM\JoinColumn(onDelete="CASCADE")
```

did I missed an update or something ?

Comment: I don't think doctrine has a default value for cascade (or at least since quite a while). What is your current doctrine version and did you recently upgrade ?

Comment: doctrine 2.10.3, no recent update

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Even `bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql` showed nothing related to the foreign key change.
Then found this issue https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/issues/293

After running command `bin/console cache:clear`, I got the migration and schema commands returning with the desired result (drop + add foreign key)